# InDesign Scripting: Deleting elements from the structure panel

Tags: javascript, xml, adobe-indesign

I've imported some XML files inside InDesign (you can see the structure in the picture below) and I've also created a script to get some statistics concerning this hierarchy.

For example, to count the "free" elements:

```
var items = app.activeDocument.xmlElements.everyItem();
var items1 = items.xmlElements.itemByName("cars");
var cars = items1.xmlElements.everyItem();
var c_free = cars.xmlElements.itemByName("free");
var cars_free = c_free.xmlElements.count().length;
```

- I also have apartments in my structure that's why I'm using itemByName.

The code above returns the correct number of free cars in my structure.

What I'm trying to do - without any luck so far - is to target those free items (inside cars) and either delete all of them or a specific number.

My last attempt was using:

```
var del1 = myInputGroup2.add ("button", undefined, "Delete All");
del1.onClick = function () {
    cars.xmlElements.everyItem().remove();
}
```

inside a dialog I've created.

Any suggestions will be appreciated cause I'm really stuck here.

[image: Strucure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use XPath for this. You can use evaluateXPathExpression to create an array of the elements you want to target. Assuming your root element is cars and it contains elements called cars1, and you want to delete all free elements within a cars1 element, you could do something like:

```
var myDoc = app.activeDocument;
//xmlElements[0] is your root element, in this case "cars". The xPath expression is evaluated from cars.
//evaluateXPathExpression returns an array of all of the free elements that are children of cars. 
var myFrees = myDoc.xmlElements[0].evaluateXPathExpression("cars1/free");
for (var i = myFrees.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
    myFrees[i].remove();
}
```

Tweaking this would require some knowledge of xPath, but it's not terribly hard to learn the basics and it does seem like the simplest approach.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I managed to get the correct XPath using this expression:


    var cars_free_array = app.activeDocument.xmlElements[0].evaluateXPathExpression("cars/*[starts-with(local-name(),'cars')]/free");


I also added an alert to see the length of this array and it matched the number of the free elements I'm targeting.


However, the remove() function is not working.

    for (var i = 0; i < cars_free_array.length; i++){
    cars_free_array[i].remove();
    }


The above code does nothing :/

Comment: It occurs to me that this needs to loop backwards; we're removing xmlElements from the collection so the indices are changing. I'll edit to indicate that. Still, I'd expect you to see at least some of them removed. If backwards looping doesn't work, I'm not sure what it could be; xmlElement doesn't have a locked attribute or any other obvious way to keep it from being changed.

Comment: It's not working... I don't what else to do. I'll try to experiment a bit more and if I find a solution, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I think your main problem was that XMLElements hasn't a itemByName method. You can only reference XMLElements through their indeces or ids.

Secondly you assume that you got xmlElements from XPath expression but it's likely that you got nothing as your xpath seems uncorrect.

```js
var myFrees = myDoc.xmlElements[0].evaluateXPathExpression("./cars1/free");
var n = myFrees.length;

if ( !n ) {
  alert("Aucun élément trouvé");
}
else {
  while (n--) myFrees[n].remove();
}
```

You need to start your expression by setting the origin of your xpath. Here a dot "./" is used to tell you want to look for cars1/free xml elements at the "root" of the xmlelement. Using "//" on the contrary would have returned any cars/free items unregardingly of their locations.

Comment: My script is used to populate statistics of the items in the Structure panel as you can see in the image [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28352937/statistics.jpg)  
(the button circled in red is used to call the function that delete the auto free elements - 144 items).  
Moreover, when I alert cars_free_array I get a list of XML objects as seen [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28352937/alert.jpg) which means that I do get the elements I want to remove (if i alert cars_free_array.length I get 144 which is the number of free cars in my structure).

Comment: It may mean that the xmlElement is applied to some layout content that might be locked or an hidden ayer at this time. For debugguing I would advice a try/catch statement and look at the error execution message.